# Strange behavior in TextBox.Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

TextBox.Text is string property

but if you assign an int, decimal ..etc to it it works!!

```
int x = 5;

Textbox1.Text = x; // it works
```

any body know why can tell me ?

Comment: and weridly string x = 3 , will raise an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because of [Implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2(VS.71).aspx) conversion.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) is the full list of implicit numberic conversions

As Sonny has pointed out, the following is true from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2wkh0tk(VS.71).aspx)

> If Option Strict is On, the above
>   example raises a compiler error. If
>   Option Strict is Off, however, the
>   conversion is performed implicitly,
>   even though this implicit conversion
>   may cause an error at runtime. For
>   this reason, you should always use
>   Option Strict On.

Comment: As a side note: it's preferred not to run with Option Explicit or Option Strict turned to off. (Those are the VB settings, I'm assuming C# is the same).

Answer (score 2):

C# will allow implicit conversion to String from a numeric type. So this works because it is equivalent to:

`TextBox1.Text = x.ToString();`

Answer (score 2):

Value types such as int, double, etc. have a ToString() method that is automatically called for you. You can see this by typing x.ToString();
What is really happening under the hood is that the value type is being "boxed" into a corresponding reference type (class) and the class has the ToString method.

Answer (score 1):

as already pointed out this is because of implict conversion.

An other example:

```
?Console.WriteLine(1)
1
?Console.WriteLine("1")
1
```

because

```
Console.WriteLine(1) == Console.WriteLine(1.ToString())
```